# How to find hugepage size on system?

Tags: linux, centos, kernel, memory

I am getting following two different result. which one i should consider for `Hugepage`?

```
[root@server ~]# getconf PAGESIZE
4096
[root@server ~]# grep -i hugepagesize /proc/meminfo 
Hugepagesize:     2048 kB
```

My kernel on `CentOS 7.1`

```
Linux localhost.localdomain 3.10.0-123.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Jun 30 12:09:22 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously for Hugepage is Hugepagesize. PAGESIZE is for (non-huge) pages in virtual memory.

I will leave an URL explaining it better:

https://wiki.debian.org/Hugepages

Other tidbits:

shmall determines the total amount of shared memory to be allocated using its value multipled by the OS pagesize.

"pagesize = getconf PAGE_SIZE"

"Divide the SHMMAX value by the Hugepagesize to get SHMALL"

Comment: i need correct value because i am calculating `kernel.shmmax` and `kernel.shmall` so i want to know which value i should consider

Comment: Post edited for clarity.

Comment: insteresting, just adding some tidbits.

Comment: so `pagesize` will be multipled and total result of that divide by  `Hugepagesize`  very interesting...

Comment: Just a few tidbits I got here and there. I recommend you to follow the official Oracle documentation.